# How to read same file multiple time in javascript

Tags: javascript, file

I have a requirement where I have to read the file and plot the data using javascript. My file will be updated often so i need to read it every time before plotting.

I have written code to do it once i.e., reading the file and store the data js variables.

index.html

```
<input type="file" id="csvFileInput" onchange="importData(this.files)"accept=".csv">
```

fileRead.js

```
 <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<body>
<input type="file" id="csvFileInput" accept=".csv" onchange="importData(this.files)"><br>

<input type="submit" id="Pfit" value="fit">
<script>
  var F_load = [];
  var v = [];
  
   var csvpoints = [];
       function importData(files){
       k = files
        handleFiles(files);
       // plotGraph("div1",F_load, v);
        Pfit.disabled = false;
       }
 
       function handleFiles(files) {
      // Check for the various File API support.
      if (window.FileReader) {
          // FileReader are supported.
          getAsText(files[0]);
      } else {
          alert('FileReader are not supported in this browser.');
      }
    }

    function getAsText(fileToRead) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      // Read file into memory as UTF-8      
      reader.readAsText(fileToRead);
      // Handle errors load
      reader.onload = loadHandler;
      reader.onerror = errorHandler;
    }

    function loadHandler(event) {
      var csv = event.target.result;
      processData(csv);
    }

    function processData(csv) {
        var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        var lines = [];
        for (var i=1; i<allTextLines.length; i++) {
             data = allTextLines[i].split(';');
        csvpoints.push(data);
        F_load.push(data[0]);
        v.push(data[1]);
 
    }
           console.log(F_load);
}
function errorHandler(evt) {
    if(evt.target.error.name == "NotReadableError") {
        alert("Canno't read file !");
    }
}
const fitButton=document.getElementById('Pfit');
fitButton.addEventListener('click',event => {
var k = document.getElementById("csvFileInput").file
importData(k)
});
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, it works for the first time. but when i tried to access for the second time it errored out at `getAsText(files[0]);` . Could anyone help me on this.
[image]

Comment: "It errored out" is not diagnostic. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page: you need to post the error.

Comment: Are you trying to have the user choose a file with `input`, then automatically re-read the data multiple times? Surely this is disallowed for good reason. The user should be required to explicitly grant permission each time to read a file one time. Browser JS isn't allowed to go poking into the file system on users' computers like that. Also, please post errors as text, not images.

Comment: you can put the the file into a `blob`.

Comment: Putting file into a blob helps in preventing the user to select file everytin? I am not sure how to put a file into blob. Could give me a short example?

Comment: `file` is already a `blob`, you just have to put it somewhere in a variable

Comment: For security reason, you can only read the user-chosen file (as many times as you want but that file only). Once closed, you lose access to that file until the user selects it again.

Comment: I also tried putting that file into other variable. But i did not help me. I got a similar error saying invalid argument.

Comment: I just want to read the same file everytime but it keeps on updating. Could you provide a code snippet for reading it multiple times.? It would be a great help if you could do that.